# What is the quickest way to download a file from the internet in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am writing an application that needs to download several pages from the internet. The pages themselves are not that big, however, it takes an extremely long time. I am currently using WebClient.DownloadDataAsync. I have tried giving the application a high priority in NetBalancer, to no avail. What is the fastest way that doesn't use an external library to download a file from the internet in .Net?

Comment: What's the bottleneck?  Usually transferring the data over the network is the slowest part of the operation, and no amount of code can fix that.

Comment: I have no idea what the bottleneck is. I have a progress bar that tracks how many downloads have been completed, and each one takes up to 5 minutes. Again, these are relatively small files. Nothing that justifies 5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe you should try to identify the bottleneck.

Comment: I've tried checking NetBalancer, and it shows that no data is downloaded or uploaded except for less than a second once in a while in which the upload rate is 200 bytes / second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't what is the quickest way. Nothing downloads at 5min per page (unless the page is extremely large or the connection is extremely slow). You need to identify which part of your code that is causing the "slowness".

Perhaps a simple timer will help:

```
Dim viStart As Long = Now.Ticks
'...
'...
'...
Dim viEnd As Long = Now.Ticks - viStart
```

Put those at different parts of your code to see which one is slowing the whole thing down. Then post your question here.

Comment: Thanks for actually helping me identify the bottleneck. Apparently, parsing was the real issue, taking up most of the time. I didn't know parsing XML could take so long. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try running in synchronously.

```
void Main()
{
    var remotefile = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";
    var localfile = @"c:\temp\logo.png";
    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        wc.DownloadFile(remotefile,localfile);
}
```

Comment: As I've said, I'm using DownloadDataAsync. However, the event handler is running in the main thread. Should I make a separate thread for the event handler?

Comment: I'm suggesting running it synchronously just to simplify things I suppose. If the code is really this simple I would suggest getting someone involved to check the route from end to end.